# Understanding data structures in Javascript oriented way

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm an average javascript guy. Lately I'm doing some javascript in an area where people are not js programmers. They use these weird words. I was wondering if someone can explain the data structures in a javascript oriented way. (like maybe a js example).

I looked them up on wikipedia but they use all this non-js thinking/terminology which throws me off.

From a non-js prespective we have four basic data structures:

1. Linked list - I think they also call this hash table? which is just key value pairs?
2. Array - js has this
3. Binary Tree - no js equivalent?
4. Heap - no js equivalent?

Comment: `Array`: Collection of similar objects (integers, JSONs, others);
`Binay Tree`, Sorted array in javascript in specified order.

Comment: Lists aren't key value pairs, they are a continuous list of nodes/links that carry some data type and a reference/pointer to the next item in the list. [BinaryTree](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1899-javascript-data-structures-the-binary-tree.html) is done and I'd assume any typical ds is possible.

Comment: I think you are confusing *data structures* with *data types*. Since JavaScript has an Object data *type*, you can build all of the mentioned data structures on top of it. Simplest example: Arrays. There are no native arrays in JavaScript, they are just specialized objects. Similarly you can implement a Heap or Binary tree with objects. To be able to implement the data structures you have to understand their concept first, which is language-agnostic.

Comment: You can probably find JavaScript implementations of popular data structures on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code).

Comment: "non-js thinking/terminology which throws me off" - it's basic computer science. get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for all the input.

Out of everything the most helpful was a link provided by @ChiefTwoPencils

The website is [i-programmer.info](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript.html)

I learned there are six types of data structures:

1. Linked Lists
2. Binary Trees
3. Tries
4. Stacks
5. Queues
6. Vectors / ArrayLists
7. Hash Tables

i-programmer.info has these data structure resources:

- Typed Arrays - [Part I](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6135-javascript-data-structures-typed-arrays.html) & [Part II](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6151-javascript-data-structures-typed-arrays-ii.html)
- Linked Lists - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/5328-javascript-data-structures-the-linked-list.html)
- String - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/4138-javascript-data-structures-the-string-object.html)
- Array - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/2865-javascript-data-structures-the-array-object.html)
- Associative Array - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html)
- Lisp-like List - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/2380-javascript-data-structures-a-lisp-like-list.html)
- Binary Tree - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1899-javascript-data-structures-the-binary-tree.html)
- Stacks - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1674-javascript-data-structures-stacks-queues-and-deques.html)
- Collection Object - [Article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1504-j.html)

They don't have heaps and stuff so I'm looking on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=heap+javascript&fulltext=Search) like @elclanrs recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is javascript is an object,

An Array is a type of object, specifically known as an array object.

A string is a type of object, specifically known as a string.

a Binary tree is a type of object, known as just an object.

a heap is a type of object, known as just an object.

The browser interface is a object.

Other APIs using javascript as a scripting language are objects.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfRkdm_rq5E

A binary tree may not be a native object to Javascript. That just means you need to build the object.

Comment: You should watch the follow up to that video, which invalidates most of what you just said https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17s2qBhkDOs

Comment: Everything is javascript is an object -> numbers, boolean, strings (in string literal sense) are not objects.

Comment: @bluebelle and elclanrs, I would agree that numbers, boolean, strings are not used as objects because that would be confusing, but they actually operate in mostly the same way as any other object; An prototype can be attached to them ... I don't suggest doing it because the code will become to difficult to read and understand, it will cause heads to explode.

Comment: You cannot attach a property to a number or a string literal.

Comment: @elclanrs that is true, but you can attach a property to numbers (4).string = "I have a property";

Comment: Lets just get this over with: There are six data types in JavaScript: Null, Undefined, String, Number, Boolen and Object. Some primitive types (String, Number, Boolean) have Object equivalents. When you are trying to use a value of these types as object (e.g. property access), it gets autoboxed to an object. That object exist only temporary and is discarded after the operation. I think what the statement "everything is an object" is trying to express is that things like functions or arrays are objects, which may be surprising for someone coming from other languages.

Comment: @Wayne well `var m = 4; m.foo = 3; var p = m.foo; // p is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript have objects which can be represented as key-value pair.

The key must be and will be converted to a string.
Here is an object

```
{
 name: "Moo", age: 20
}
```

You can already represent a Binary Tree by using this notation, though not as pretty as C/C++/Java counterpart.

```
{
 node: 20,
 left: {
   node: 10,
   left: null,
   right: null
 },
 right: {
   node: 30,
   left: null,
   right: null
 }
}
```

You can obtain the value of the field using `someObject.field` or `someObject["field"]`, both are equivalent!.

List and Arrays can be represented using javascript Arrays, however they are also an object.
Observe this.

```
var myArray = [2,3,5];
myArray[0]; // 2
myArray["0"]; // 2
myArray["push"]; // function push()..... etc etc
```

Does this means `myArray` also an object? well yes. It just happened that your browser is smart enough that when you `console.log` it, it shows the data and hides the methods properly.